# Swift Firebase: how to check user is verified after send email?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

After creating account i sending an email with verification link:

```
func sendVerificationMail() {
        if self.authUser != nil && !self.authUser!.isEmailVerified {
            self.authUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in

                // TODO Notify user email was sent or not because of error

            })
        } else {

            // TODO Notify everything is OK

        }
    }
```

And in other place i checking it confirmed:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil && Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainScreen", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notLoggedView", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Even if confirmed, i always go to notLoggedView. Somebody can explain why?

Comment: have you checked the value of isEmailVerified ? have you verified the email ?

Comment: @jawadAli I checking it in viewDidAppear function inside if. Yes i clicked link too.

Comment: so Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified is false even you verify email ?

Comment: @jawadAli yes :/ After commenting section with email verification, it works fine.

Comment: The `isEmailVerified` will only be updated once the user gets a new ID token from the server. So this can be when you restart the app, when you [force a token refresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#getidtokenresultforcingrefresh:completion:), or when the token refreshes (which happens every hours).

Comment: And if I'm understanding right, it still takes you to the login screen even after the user should be technically logged in? (It doesn't skip right to the VC you want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue and to solve it I have to reload the profile. Try this.

```
func loginUser() {

       Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (error) in

                  if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                  } else {
                          if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil && Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
                             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainScreen", sender: self)
                          } else {
                                  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notLoggedView", sender: self).  
                               }
                         }
                 })
}
```

Also, instead of writing `Auth.auth().currentUser` every time you can store that in a `variable`. And, you can use this function wherever you want.

```
if let authUser = Auth.auth().currentUser { //You can also get  current user like this in a safe way
  //Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: @Yardi Anytime!

Comment: A little advice, if user not logged, this code causes error, before reload you need to put if currentUser != nil

Comment: That's why I suggested safe unwrapping --> `if let authUser = Auth.auth().currentUser { //You can also get  current user like this in a safe way
  //Do your stuff here
}`